# Send silent push notification using firebase to wake the app if it was killed

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, uilocalnotification

I know how to send silent notification using firebase and it works fine but when the app is killed it doesn't awakes the app to execute the code that registers the local notification!

So how could I send a silent push notification that awakes the app using Firebase to register a local notification if the app isn't active (also not in background) ??

UPDATE:

I am using this function to receive the silent push notification and register the local notification and it works fine but when the app is force-quit it doesn't register the local notification which means the silent notification doesn't wake up the app

```
application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)
```

I also found someone saying that it if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

so if anyone knows anyway I can make silent notification that wakes up the app when the user has force-quit it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there is no way to relaunch the app when user kills it.

From Apple Forums:

> Also keep in mind that if you kill your app from the app switcher
>   (i.e. swiping up to kill the app) then the OS will never relaunch the
>   app regardless of push notification or background fetch. In this case
>   the user has to manually relaunch the app once and then from that
>   point forward the background activities will be invoked. -pmarcos
>   (Apple worker)

https://devforums.apple.com/message/873265#873265